# Как сделать выборку между двумя датами?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Есть таблица следующего вида:

CARS: id, title, year_start, year_end

year_start - год выпуска автомобиля ОТ, year_end - год выпуска автомобиля ДО

Я написал такой запрос:

```
select id, year_start, year_end from `cars`
where year_start >= 2014 AND year_end <= 2018
```

Однако этот запрос не совсем релевантный. Он не выдает мне записи, например, если у них year_start=2015, year_end = 2023 и так далее. Это логично. Но как мне сделать так, чтобы мой запрос выдавал все записи, который попадают в нужный мне диапазон дат?

Проиллюстрирую свой пример:

```
select id, year_start, year_end from `cars`
where year_start >= 2014 AND year_end <= 2018
```

[image: Выборка 1]

```
select id, year_start, year_end from `bids`
where year_start >= 2014 AND year_end <= 2023
```

[image: Выборка 2]

Как правильно написать запрос, чтобы, например, при выборке **year_start** = 2014, **year_end** = 2018, выдало и записи с **year_start** = 2015, **year_end** = 2023

UPD: загружаю пример того, как выглядит фильтр на клиенте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: year_start >= 2014 and year_start <= 2018 or year_end >= 2014 and year_end <= 2018, с учетом того, что year_start <= year_end, получаем year_start >= 2014 or year_end <= 2018

Answer (score 0):

так пойдет?

select id, year_start, year_end from `cars`
where year_start <= 2018 AND year_end >= 2014

[image: схема возможных вариантов]
возможных вариантов (как я понимаю) всего 4, всё остальное не должно попадать. "популярная машина" - это машина которая выпускается долго (начало выпуска раньше 2014, окончание выпуска после 2018), остальные варианты, думаю, понятны?

Comment: Кажется вы не поняли или не дочитали вопрос до конца. Я уже пробовал этот способ, однако он не покрывает нужный диапазон. Сейчас этот вариант является наиболее пригодным, но не идеальным для решения моей задачи:
year_start >= 2014 and year_start <= 2018 or year_end >= 2014 and year_end <= 2018,

Comment: @Vanya228 У тебя везде "year_start >=", я же предложил другое: year_start <= 2018 AND year_end >= 2014. Может я не понял что тебе нужно? Нарисуй схему всех возможных вариантов (как у меня) и приложи к вопросу.

Comment: @ Vlad Chapl я обновил вопрос, приложив скрин как на клиенте фильтр выглядит, может так станет чуть яснее что мне нужно

Comment: вроде же должно работать: select id, year_start, year_end from cars where year_start <= user_year2 AND year_end >= user_year1    Правильно ли я понимаю, что в БД записано с какого по какой год выпускалась конкретная марка и тебе нужно показать все марки, которые выпускались с user_year1  до user_year2 хотя бы частично (т.е. не нужно полное вхождение, достаточно пересечение границы веременного интервала)?